# SQLCMD create temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I'm trying to get data from different SQL servers, and insert them into an temp table and afterwards process the data, all by using SQLCMD.

I have the code for the process and it works perfect if you have only one database:

```
DECLARE @main table(Id int identity(1,1), Country nvarchar(5), [Message] nvarchar(200), Date datetime, pcname nvarchar(200))
:connect Plant1
use Plant1
GO
INSERT INTO @main 
SELECT 'Plant1', Message, date, pcname FROM log.easyhmi WHERE DATE > GETDATE() -15 AND [Message] LIKE 'MakeChangeOver | Verify changeover runinng processInstance Id: %'ORDER BY 1 DESC
GO

:connect Plant2
use Plant2
GO
INSERT INTO @main
SELECT 'Plant2', Message, date, pcname FROM log.easyhmi WHERE DATE > GETDATE() -15 AND [Message] LIKE 'MakeChangeOver | Verify changeover runinng processInstance Id: %'ORDER BY 1 DESC
GO

:connect Plant3
use Plant3
GO
INSERT INTO @main
SELECT 'Plant3', Message, date, pcname FROM log.easyhmi WHERE DATE > GETDATE() -15 AND [Message] LIKE 'MakeChangeOver | Verify changeover runinng processInstance Id: %'ORDER BY 1 DESC
GO

--Process data here......
```

But if I add more databases, then it can't find the `@main`.

Is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: have a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86852/can-a-temporary-table-be-shared-across-sessions). Local variables don't move across sessions as you can already see, so you might need to consider alternative solutions to the problem. Is there any way for you to create a "permentant" temp table ie. an actual table on your local machines DB?

Comment: Do you want to get data from different servers or get data from different db's within the same Server.

Comment: Table variables are not visible between batches, separated by GO. Try create a temp table instead. (@Table is a variable, #Table is a temp table).